# Running yii application on centos

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite, yii

We recentlly shifted our complete yii web application to vps server with php 5.3 and apache 2.2.16 and os - centos.

The problem is complete webapp is not working now, before it was working fine on sharedhosting.

`http://212.1.213.180/yii/requirements/` You can check the yii requirements of my app

when I tried running I got some protected/runtime invalid error then I changed permission of runtime and assets to 777 then now am getting

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CAttributeCollection in /home/wwwmobit/public_html/yii/framework/collections/CAttributeCollection.php on line 32
```

what could be the problem??

I checked mod_rewrite is enable.

you can check complete phpinfo of my site here

```
http://212.1.213.180/info.php
```

Please resolve my problem as soon as possible.

Do I need to edit framework file and make it to include_once?

Comment: What does your main `index.php` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply I found solution my self with couple of yii guys in live chat.

The solution is to uninstall apc by pecl uninstall apc 
then change permission of yii folder and assets and runtime folder in project.

Thats it.